# Residual Vs. Fitted Plot with Outliers

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, residuals

I have a model relating fuel consumption to other vehicle parameters, which produces the following Residuals Vs. Fitted plot.

[image]

**My Question:** Is the skew to the right simply an indication of outliers in the data? If so, is it safe to assume linearity of the model based on this plot?

**Additional Information:** I have plotted the factors separately using the R crPlots package, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Are there only 4 categorical variables in your model? The fitted values seem to be at a wide range of values. Are there no continuous variables? To determine linearity, it's best to plot the residuals against each variable individually, although categorical variables wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @gung. Thanks for the reply. The four factors are continuous variables. I simply changed the names to simplify the graph for this post.

Comment: Looks pretty linear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fitted values can be outlying because of two reasons:

- The predictor values are outlying
- The predictor values are quite normal compared to the other predictor variables, however the outcome is outlying because of an extreme error term.

In this case I would study the Cooks distance. If it shows the outlying outcome variables are due to a combination of predictor variables with a high Cooks distance, you might suspect there is something wrong.

And given the four predictor plots, I suspect the outlying outcomes are due to extreme values of factor 1 in combination with factor 3 (which will also result in a high Cooks Distance), and so you might question if your linear model still holds in that region.

Hope this helps and that I did not say anything foolish.